# NGINX - is there any Radius Auth Module for NGINX

Tags: authentication, nginx

Is there any radius authg module available and developed by NGINX team ? is it part of NGINX plus ? I am unable to find radius module which I can use in NGINX for http request authentication.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for radius authentication with NGINX. But at the moment its not provided by NGINX team. I assume you want a module developed by NGINX team. If not then you can use the one provided by qudreams repository in github.